# haproxy - pass original / remote ip in tcp mode

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I've got haproxy set up with keepalived for load balancing and ip failover of a percona cluster, and since it works great I'd like to use the same lb / failover for another service/daemon.

I've configured haproxy this way:

```
listen my_service 0.0.0.0:4567
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    option tcpka
    contimeout      500000
    clitimeout      500000
    srvtimeout      500000

    server host1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1:4567 check port 4567 inter 5000 rise 3 fall 3
    server host2 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2:4567 check port 4567 inter 5000 rise 3 fall 3
```

The load balancing works fine, but the service sees the IP of the load balancer instead of the actual IPs of the clients. In http mode it's quite easy to have haproxy pass along the remote IP, but how do I do in tcp mode? This is critical due to the nature of the service I need to load balance.

Thanks!
Vito

Comment: here is the full documentation of haproxy 1.6.6
https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#4-option%20transparent

Answer (score 3):

There is apparently some sort of "transparent" mode for haproxy that I've never looked at or want anything to do with, that you could try.  Otherwise, you'll need to teach whatever the backend service is about haproxy's special way of sending the original IP ("PROXY blahblah") and have the service pull the original IP out of that.

Why are you bothering with haproxy, though?  You've got keepalived already in place, and it does proper transparent load balancing, too.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply :) I am reading some stuff about 'tproxy' support, I guess this is what you meant? Also, I hadn't considered load balancing with keepalived directly for this. Does keepalived pass the original IP of the client?

Comment: Yes, keepalived keeps the original IP intact, because it's a load balancer, not a proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Just for future references, 
keepalived is a solution for failover not load balancing (maybe you mean LVS?).
the transparent proxy mode for HAProxy has nothing to do with any special way of sending the original IP, that would be the normal non-transparent HTTP mode where you can use a standardized HTTP header for this.

In my opinion the correctly answer the original question is:
You could compile transparent proxy support in HAProxy on a TPROXY enabled linux kernel.
This together with proper TPROXY supporting version + configuration of iptables on the same machine enables actual fully transparent tcp proxy support. This means that backend servers do NOT need any special configuration.

Note that this is actually not the recommended setup for HAProxy and should only be used if you absolutely need it.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the HAProxy as NAT Mode, which it still using TCP mode in Layer 4 but makes the IP transparent.

> [HAProxy Layer 4 load balancing NAT mode](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/layer-4-load-balancing-nat-mode/)

---

On the other hand, HAPorxy Transparent Mode uses HTTP mode in Layer 7, which it doesn't hit your point because there are already has `forwardfor` option in HTTP mode.

> [HAProxy layer 7 load-balancing transparent proxy mode](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/layer-7-load-balancing-transparent-proxy-mode/)

Answer (score 2):

Using `send-proxy` in your configuration (per-server) will give you the original source-ip on the recieving server side, even in TCP mode. This requires HAProxy 1.5+.

You may find more information about [Proxy Protocol](http://blog.haproxy.com/haproxy/proxy-protocol/) in [HAProxy Documentation](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/proxy-protocol.txt).

```
listen my_service 0.0.0.0:4567
mode tcp
balance leastconn
option tcpka
contimeout      500000
clitimeout      500000
srvtimeout      500000

server host1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1:4567 send-proxy check port 4567 inter 5000 rise 3 fall 3
server host2 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2:4567 send-proxy check port 4567 inter 5000 rise 3 fall 3
```

Comment: HI Nils, thanks for the solution, but when I input send-proxy, it cause the db down (haproxy can't detect the host)

Comment: same happened with me as well with DB. any solution ?

Answer (score -4):

This configuration worked for me. Source IP can be retrieved in $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']:

```
global
        [..... usual stuff .... ]   
        ssl-server-verify none

frontend  main *:5000
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/mycert_with_private_key.pem
        mode http
        option forwardfor
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
        default_backend https_server

backend https_server
        mode http
        balance leastconn
        option tcpka
        stick-table type ip size 200k expire 30m
        server srv04 192.168.1.10:443 ssl check
        server srv05 192.168.1.11:443 ssl check
```

Comment: this answer doesn't apply. the connection is not HTTP.

Comment: Are you suggesting https connection must be in tcp mode?.

Comment: No, I'm saying that the question uses tcp, and your answer only applies to http/s.

Comment: ok, good luck then, I haven't found any doc relative to haproxy in tcp mode forwarding ip. Maybe the layer where requests are processed can't pass this info.